# How to open a new tab using Python Playwright by feeding it a list of URLs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

According to the Playwright documentation, the way to open a new tab in the browser is as shown in the `scrape_post_info()` function? However, it failed to do so.

What I am currently trying to do now is to loop through each URL within the `posts` list variable and then open up the link or URL in the new tab to scrape the post details. After done scraping a post, the tab then will be closed and continue to open up the next link in a new tab to scrape the post details again until it reaches the last URL in the `posts` list variable.

```
# Loop through each URL from the `posts` list variable that contains many posts' URLs
for post in posts:
    scrape_post_info(context, post)

def scrape_post_info(context, post):

    with context.expect_page() as new_page_info:
        page.click('a[target="_blank"]')  # Opens a new tab
    new_page = new_page_info.value

    new_page.wait_for_load_state()
    print(new_page.title())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something similar for a project of mine, this is how I would do it.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

posts = ['https://playwright.dev/','https://playwright.dev/python/',]

def scrape_post_info(context, post):
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(post)
    print(page.title())
    # do whatever scraping you need to
    page.close()

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    for post in posts:
        scrape_post_info(context, post)
        # some time delay

browser.close()
```

Thing is the [code snippet](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pages#handling-new-pages) from the playwright docs is more about opening a new page after clicking a link on an existing page. Since you already have the urls ready, you can just visit each page one by one, and do your scraping.